# How to configure Doctrine in symfony2?

Tags: mysql, symfony, doctrine-orm, metadata, reverse-engineering

We use MySQL "enum" and "set" types in our project.
And we need to reverse engineer existing DB.
With the help of this http://docs.doctrine-project.org/projects/doctrine-orm/en/2.0.x/reference/tools.html#reverse-engineering recipe and custom "doctrine.php" I managed to run doctrine form "/vendors" and generate metadata.
But this docs missing entities generation part.
So I resorted to http://symfony.com/doc/2.0/cookbook/doctrine/reverse_engineering.html.
And it seems that now for "app/console" I have to solve all the problems already solved in "doctrine.php".
The question is how to at least do

```
$platform->registerDoctrineTypeMapping('enum', 'string');
```

so that it will work for "app/console doctrine"?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Looks like here it is http://symfony.com/doc/2.0/reference/configuration/doctrine.html#doctrine-dbal-configuration

Comment: Looks like you got it. Adding :
doctrine:
    dbal: ....
        mapping_types:
            enum: string

Will allow you to reverse engineer from the command line. Note however if you attempt to recreate the database via command line your enum column will be created as a string. I've yet to find the solution to this!